# How to cast a shadow properly on the edge of the hidden part of a table ?

Tags: css, user-interface, html-table

I'm trying to add a shadow to the edges of my tables when they are too large for their parent container (Horizontal Overflow).

I want to keep the background color when hovering a row but I am unable to keep the shadow while adding a background color to the row.

What is the proper way to do it?

Here is a reproduction of my issue:

```css
.table-shadow-edges > .table {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(to left, white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) 100% 0;
    background-size: 50px 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-responsive .bootgrid-table {
    table-layout: inherit!important;
}

.table-responsive {
    border: 0;
    width: 300px !important; /* For Demo Purpose */
}

.table-shadow-edges {
    background-size: 10px 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 100% 0;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 100%;
}

.table-responsive {
    min-height: 0.01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 0;
}

table.bootgrid-table thead tr {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3c7eca !important;
    border-top: 0;
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)!important ; 
}

.table tbody tr:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #dce8f6 !important;
    color: #3C7ECA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive table-shadow-edges">
   <table id="authorities-table" class="table table-striped bootgrid-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor sortable"><span class="text">
               Name
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="companies" class="text-left" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor sortable"><span class="text">
               # Company
               </span><span class="md icon md-expand-less"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="users" class="text-left" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor sortable"><span class="text">
               # User
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="devices" class="text-left" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor "><span class="text">
               # Devices
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="deviceLists" class="text-left" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor "><span class="text">
               # Device Lists
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="enabled" class="text-left" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor sortable"><span class="text">
               enabled
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="commands" class="text-center" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="column-header-anchor "><span class="text">
               COMMANDS
               </span><span class="md icon"></span></a>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
 <tr data-row-id="3">
            <td class="text-left" style="">Company3</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">211</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">466</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">2047</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">70</td>
            <td class="text-left" style=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok c-green"></i></td>
            <td class="text-center" style=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default m-r-10 authority-edit" data-id="1"><i class="md md-edit m-r-0"></i></button></td>
         </tr>
 <tr data-row-id="2">
            <td class="text-left" style="">Company3</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">211</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">466</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">2047</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">70</td>
            <td class="text-left" style=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok c-green"></i></td>
            <td class="text-center" style=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default m-r-10 authority-edit" data-id="1"><i class="md md-edit m-r-0"></i></button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-row-id="1">
            <td class="text-left" style="">Company3</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">211</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">466</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">2047</td>
            <td class="text-left" style="">70</td>
            <td class="text-left" style=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok c-green"></i></td>
            <td class="text-center" style=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default m-r-10 authority-edit" data-id="1"><i class="md md-edit m-r-0"></i></button></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

And here a screenshot of my UI issue : 
[image: Screenshot of the visual issue]

Comment: you can try giving the background-color with opacity that should solve the problem (background: #dce8f6 !important; ==> rgba(x,x,x,0.1)). Inbetween you don't have to write !important everywhere, Its a bad practice just write the rule specific enough

Comment: I will test this. The `!important` are not on my code base but was needed to overwrite the values from the Bootstrap CDN used in the SO editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `background-color` with opacity on your selected rows.